# refreshing previous activity in current activity

Tags: android, android-studio

Let "**A**" be the first activity where am getting a response from server and saved in shared preference/(using intent)  and then send to second activity "**B**" and showing a values in textview. Now my question is , is it possible to refresh the first activity in second activity without going back to first activity because the server might be update a particular value,so that the value which am showing in second activity should me changed automatically.(using timer/thread).
please give me an idea. Thanks in advance.

for eg:
value of car=20,van=30 in first class, am showing it in second class.
but suddenly after few min/sec car value is changed to car=50, now i have to update a value in second activity.

Comment: what you are trying to do is achieved using service and not from activity.

Comment: no service. only activty

Comment: Use Service with timer,set time interval call the service and get response.

Comment: Try using custom interface

Comment: @Daryl your approach looks much more complicated and beyond the standards of android programming. Can you update your question with what exactly is the use of this approach in your actual app. I hope people can then help you with much more reliable solution

Comment: @mohammed atif, Actually my app depends on webpage ,where in first activity i recieve a response from server (eg: car=20$,van=30$) ,i showed this value in second activity but 10 secs later ,in webpage ,the client changed the value (car=50$,van=30$), i cant come back to first activity for refreshing,at that same time, i have to update the value in second activity (which should be refreshing a second activity automatically every 20 to 30 secs).

Comment: So basically you are making API calls after regular time intervals from Activity A?

Comment: like that @Mohammed

Answer (score 2):

what you are going to do is not a good practice. when you go the second activity the first activity is stopped.

you'd better have a third class to handle your network stuff and then access that third class from wherever and whenever you want.

Comment: thanks @amir Ziarati, can you please explain me brifely (sample code) to understand easily.

Comment: e.g. you can create a third class called "NetworkInteracator" and put some static methods for getting the network data and returning them as models. you can create a callback class and send an implementation of that callback to those methods so that they call your callback withe the returning data as the callback argument whenever asynchronous task is done.

Comment: use asynchHttp library https://guides.codepath.com/android/Using-Android-Async-Http-Client

Answer (score 2):

You should use a Service to fetch data from Server and save it into a common place like Database, Files, Singleton Class or Content Provider. Both of your activities should fetch data from that storage after a particular interval of time. Suppose data get changed on Server and your service will fetch it and store it locally (in DB, Singleton Class, File) and your activity can easily read that data in onResume or any other callback method.

Comment: whether it will change automatically ?. Or i have to refresh the second activity automatically for particular time period

Answer (score 1):

Use a ContentProvider to store your data and then register observers in the Activities that should be aware of changes.
See [https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver.html#registerContentObserver(android.net.Uri, boolean, android.database.ContentObserver](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver.html#registerContentObserver(android.net.Uri,%20boolean,%20android.database.ContentObserver)).

Answer (score 1):

You can store you model class inside Singleton class,so whatever values is getting update,just update your singleton class and when you came back to Activity **A** call you initview function so your screen is getting refreshed.

Comment: if i enter into a second activity, i wont come back to first activity to be refreshed .

Answer (score 1):

Ideally you must be using service for any work related to multiple downloads or works that are supposed to outside the activity too.

In your case, you can have a `service` that makes an API call to your server to fetch the latest values. (Much more reliable if you use sockets).

Once the service fetches the values, write it to your [Realm database](https://realm.io/products/realm-mobile-database/), and in your activity wherever you are using these values you can have

```
realm.addChangeListener(new RealmChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChange() {

            }
        });
```

this callback will be called whenever there is data change in your database. This way you will always be in sync.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a *static variable* and use that variable during updation, or call [`startActivityForResult()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult(android.content.Intent,%20int)) and update value in [`onActivityResult()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onActivityResult(int,%20int,%20android.content.Intent))

Comment: Don't use static, it may cause memory leaks, not a good idea.

Comment: @KaveeshKanwal I am agree to your view, thats why i suggest two way of doing this, he may also clear variable on first activity destroys time

Answer (score 0):

Instead of shared preference you can use SQLite DB and use content provider mechanism to update your UI. That is, you can use cursor loader to update your data.

Make activity A extend cursor loader and use the callbacks to update your UI in activity A. When ever your data gets modified in the SQLite DB it will automatically reflect in the UI, provided you use cursor to update the UI.

I generally use [this](https://github.com/BoD/android-contentprovider-generator) library for my DB related operations and UI updation using cursor loaders. This approach is the most modular approach when you server data is constantly changing. 
[Here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-provider-basics.html) is the official doc.

Comment: I suggest you to migrate to Realm, it has in built datasetchange listeners. And much more economical and easy to use than SQLite